Build and Use Netxduo Stack
So im trying to build and use the Netxduo Stack on linux for my study project. I tried several approaches but it doesn't seem to work.
First of all i found out that the netxduo Stack needs 2 additional components to work:

threadx
filex

ThreadX
I started to build the threadx library (without netxduo and filex) and tested the given demo.
This Part worked fine without much complications
I followed the given instructions: https://github.com/eclipse-threadx/threadx
Combining ThreadX with NetXDuo and FileX
Now to the part where i am failing.
I tried adding the libs in the CMakeLists like this:
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/filex-master
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/netxduo-master

The Build process finished without erros but it seems like something went wrong anyways.
First of all the build process created 3 seperate lib files: libnetxduo.a, libfilex.a and libthreadx.a.
I tried to merge the files in the following way:
ar -rcT liball.a libnetxduo.a libfilex.a libthreadx.a

Now i tried to run several demos from the NetXDuo samples and failed.
Build command:
gcc -o sample demo_mqtt_client.c liball.a

Error:
/usr/bin/ld: liball.a: error adding symbols: No such file or directory

I guess there might be something wrong with the way I am merging the lib files but I cant find out where I am wrong.
Other problem I came along in the process of trying different things: Many undefined references - which is confusing because the build process didnt show any erros
I hope someone has experience in using the NetXDuo stack and can help me out here.
